# How do you deploy and build an application using bitbucket and AppHarbor?

Tags: bitbucket, appharbor

Here is what I've done so far.

1. Grabbed the Repository URL from AppHarbor
2. In bitbucket, I configured the AppHarbor service to use that token.
3. For the project, I entered the same name of the application I used in AppHarbor (I have no idea what a slug is)
4. I saved the settings
5. I granted apphb read permissions in Access Management
6. I pushed to bitbucket.  I even created a dummy changeset to make sure it would get a new push
7. In AppHarbor, I clicked on "Build URL" and it tells me that my URL was succesfully copied to the clipboard.

I followed the guide to the letter (well, with the exception of the slug, so I'm expceting that is the issue).

Comment: Here's a description of what a slug is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slug_(web_publishing)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Steps to Follow and what gets filled in where:

On BitBucket:

1. Apphb needs read access to the repository (if it's private)
2. Go to admin
3. Add Service: AppHarbor
4. Token is the UglyValue from the "authorization=UglyValue" part of the build url
5. Project Name is the last part of the url when looking at that application on AppHarbor. So https://appharbor.com/applications/slug-is-here would use "slug-is-here"

Then you are good to go. You can get more complicated than that (like branches and whatnot) but that's the basic setup.